# Spacy -- ImportError: preshed.maps does not export expected C function map_clear

Tags: python-3.x, import, conda, spacy

I am trying to import `spacy` in vain.

```
>>> import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 24, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\functions.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..matcher import Matcher
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\spacy\matcher\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .phrasematcher import PhraseMatcher
  File "phrasematcher.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.matcher.phrasematcher
ImportError: preshed.maps does not export expected C function map_clear
```

I updated `conda` and then run `update conda all`.  I removed the previous version of `python` and installed the newest one (3.8).  I uninstalled `spacy` and reinstalled it.  Nothing worked.

The last time I worked with `spacy` was 3 weeks ago and I did not face any problem.  All of a sudden this exception erupted out of nowhere.

What is your understanding of the situation?  Any ideas on how to debug the problem or remedy the failure?

Comment: This is very similar to [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255926/can-not-import-spacy-importerror-preshed-maps-does-not-export-expected-c-func), it may be best to delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by re-installing preshed with the `--upgrade` flag.